# Varnish configured, socket(): Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: apache, centos, magento2, varnish

I am working on Centos 6.8 with Apache 2.4 and I had no trouble installing varnish and configured everything correctly for my Magento 2 site.

I have installed a SLL Certificate so I added the `-p feature=+esi_ignore_https` to my sysconfig file.

everything looks good at first

```
>  service varnish restart 
>  Stopping Varnish Cache:                       [  OK  ] 
>  Starting Varnish Cache:                       [  OK  ]
```

Then when I Start the Varnish CLI with

```
> varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
> 
> Type 'help' for command list.   
> Type 'quit' to close CLI session. 
> Type 'start' to launch worker process.
> 
> **socket(): Address family not supported by protocol**
```

and when I enter start I get an endless Loop of this

```
Child cleanup complete
socket(): Address family not supported by protocol
child (30530) Started
Child (30530) said Child starts
Child (30530) died signal=6
Child (30530) Panic message:
Assert error in vca_acct(), cache/cache_acceptor.c line 386:
  Condition((listen(ls->sock, cache_param->listen_depth)) == 0) not true.
errno = 98 (Address already in use)
thread = (cache-acceptor)
version = varnish-4.0.4 revision 386f712
ident = Linux,2.6.32-042stab113.11,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit,epoll
Backtrace:
  0x432425: varnishd() [0x432425]
  0x40d71d: varnishd() [0x40d71d]
  0x7f105722aaa1: /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7aa1) [0x7f105722aaa1]
  0x7f1056f77bcd: /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f1056f77bcd]
```

Also when try I to log into varnishlog

> Can't open VSM file (Abandoned VSM file (Varnish not running?)
>   /var/lib/varnish/patriciasouths.com/_.vsm )

Comment: You know Varnish doesn't support HTTPS, right? You have to use something like NGINX for the HTTPS termination and then pass to Varnish.

Answer (score 0):

service varnish start
Starting Varnish Cache: Error: Cannot open socket: :6081: Address family not supported by protocol

So this is really dumb.. the default install is this..

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
             -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -p thread_pool_min=${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS} \
             -p thread_pool_max=${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS} \
             -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
             -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
```

Here we have a variable to use ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}... but its NOT DEFINED PREVIOUSLY!

```
# Telnet admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
```

DOH! So add it.

```
# Telnet admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
```

Starting Varnish Cache:                                    [  OK  ]

varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.10-1.el6 FAIL from https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/el/6/SRPMS